# Avoid re-rendering whole list when images are added in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Im having an issue with my react component where my item list re-renders EVERY time a new image is added.

Here is my useEffect that I use to load image urls from the database:

```
const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState({});

  // Effect to fetch image URLs and store them in the state
  useEffect(() => {
    const getImageUrls = async () => {
      const urls = {};

      for (const [index, dataItem] of selectedData.entries()) {
        const { question, parts } = dataItem;
        let questionUrls = [];

        // Loop to fetch images for each part of the question
        for (let i = 1; i <= parts; i++) {
          const imageName = `${question}${i}`;
          const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
            .from('ocr-questions')
            .createSignedUrl(`football/images/${imageName}`, 2 * 60 * 1000);

          if (!error) {
            questionUrls.push({ url: data, isFirstImage: i === 1, imageNumber: index + 1 });
          }
        }

        urls[dataItem.id] = questionUrls;
      }

      // Merge the newly fetched URLs with the existing ones in the state
      setImageUrls((prevImageUrls) => ({ ...prevImageUrls, ...urls }));
    };

    getImageUrls();
  }, [selectedData]);
```

The selectedData is passed from the parent component - where the user can select options and they will be displayed with this component. The images are displayed like this:

```
<Box sx={{ p: 2 }}>
          {selectedData.length > 0 ? (
            <List>
              {selectedData.map((dataItem, index) => (
                <ListItem key={dataItem.id}>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={
                      <>
                        {imageUrls[dataItem.id] ? (
                          imageUrls[dataItem.id].map((imageUrl, urlIndex) => (
                            <div key={urlIndex}>
                              {imageUrl.isFirstImage && (
                                <Typography variant="body2">
                                  Question {imageUrl.imageNumber}
                                </Typography>
                              )}
                              <ResponsiveImage
                                src={imageUrl.url.signedUrl}
                                alt={`${dataItem.question} Part ${urlIndex + 1}`}
                              />
                            </div>
                          ))
                        ) : (
                          <QuestionLoadingContainer>
                            <CircularProgress size={40} />
                          </QuestionLoadingContainer>
                        )}
                      </>
                    }
                    secondary={`Paper: ${dataItem.paper}, Score: ${dataItem.score}`}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          ) : (
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              color="text.secondary"
            >
              No images selected.
            </Typography>
          )}
        </Box>
```

How can we prevent this re-rendering issue every time a user adds an image? The ideal outcome is the user adds an image and the whole list doesn't re-render.

**Update**

- Following the response from Bilal I have tried both batch and useMemo :

  const memoizedSelectedData = useMemo(() => selectedData, [selectedData]);
  useEffect(() => {
  const getImageUrls = async () => {
  const urls = {};
  for (const [index, dataItem] of memoizedSelectedData.entries()) {
  const { question, parts } = dataItem;
  let questionUrls = [];

  ```
       // Loop to fetch images for each part of the question
       for (let i = 1; i <= parts; i++) {
         const imageName = `${question}${i}`;
         const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
           .from('ocr-questions')
           .createSignedUrl(`computer-science/A2/${imageName}`, 2 * 60 * 1000);

         if (!error) {
           questionUrls.push({ url: data, isFirstImage: i === 1, questionNumber: index + 1 });
         }
       }

       urls[dataItem.id] = questionUrls;
     }

     // Set the image URLs in the state
     setImageUrls((prevImageUrls) => ({ ...prevImageUrls, ...urls }));
   };

   getImageUrls();
  ```

  }, [memoizedSelectedData]);

**here is the implementation from kind user:**

```
const ResponsiveImage = React.memo(({ imageUrl, urlIndex, imageNumber, image }) => (
    <div key={urlIndex}>
      {imageUrl.isFirstImage && <Typography variant="body2">Image {imageNumber}</Typography>}
      <img
        src={imageUrl.url.signedUrl}
        alt={`${image} Part ${urlIndex + 1}`}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 'auto',
          maxWidth: '100%',
          display: 'block',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  ));
```

Render:

```
<List>
              {selectedData.map((dataItem, index) => (
                <ListItem key={dataItem.id}>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={
                      <>
                        {/* Loop to render each image for the question */}
                        {imageUrls[dataItem.id] ? (
                          imageUrls[dataItem.id].map((imageUrl, urlIndex) => (
                            <ResponsiveImage
                              key={urlIndex}
                              imageUrl={imageUrl}
                              urlIndex={urlIndex}
                              questionNumber={imageUrl.questionNumber}
                              question={dataItem.question}
                            />
                          ))
                        ) : (
                          <QuestionLoadingContainer>
                            <CircularProgress size={40} />
                          </QuestionLoadingContainer>
                        )}
                      </>
                    }
                    secondary={`Paper: ${dataItem.paper}, Marks: ${dataItem.marks}`}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
```

**Third Update with primitives as recommended by kind user**

```
const ResponsiveImage = React.memo(
    ({ signedUrl, isFirstImage, urlIndex, questionNumber, question }) => (
      <div key={urlIndex}>
        {isFirstImage && <Typography variant="body2">Question {questionNumber}</Typography>}
        <img
          src={signedUrl}
          alt={`${question} Part ${urlIndex + 1}`}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: 'auto',
            maxWidth: '100%',
            display: 'block',
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  );
```

Render:

```
<ListItem key={dataItem.id}>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={
                      <>
                        {/* Loop to render each image for the question */}
                        {imageUrls[dataItem.id] ? (
                          imageUrls[dataItem.id].map((imageUrl, urlIndex) => (
                            <ResponsiveImage
                              key={urlIndex}
                              signedUrl={imageUrl.url.signedUrl}
                              isFirstImage={imageUrl.isFirstImage}
                              urlIndex={urlIndex}
                              questionNumber={imageUrl.questionNumber}
                              question={dataItem.question}
                            />
                          ))
                        ) : (
                          <QuestionLoadingContainer>
                            <CircularProgress size={40} />
                          </QuestionLoadingContainer>
                        )}
                      </>
                    }
                    secondary={`Paper: ${dataItem.paper}, Marks: ${dataItem.marks}`}
                  />
                </ListItem>
```

**Output of logs**

```
console.log('Type of signedUrl:', typeof signedUrl);
      console.log('Type of isFirstImage:', typeof isFirstImage);
      console.log('Type of urlIndex:', typeof urlIndex);
      console.log('Type of questionNumber:', typeof questionNumber);
      console.log('Type of question:', typeof question);
Type of signedUrl: string
Type of isFirstImage: boolean
Type of urlIndex: number
Type of questionNumber: number
Type of question: string
```

For:

```
const ResponsiveImage = React.memo(
    ({ signedUrl, isFirstImage, urlIndex, questionNumber, question }) => {
      console.log('Type of signedUrl:', typeof signedUrl);
      console.log('Type of isFirstImage:', typeof isFirstImage);
      console.log('Type of urlIndex:', typeof urlIndex);
      console.log('Type of questionNumber:', typeof questionNumber);
      console.log('Type of question:', typeof question);

      return (
        <div key={urlIndex}>
          {isFirstImage && <Typography variant="body2">Question {questionNumber}</Typography>}
          <img
            src={signedUrl}
            alt={`${question} Part ${urlIndex + 1}`}
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: 'auto',
              maxWidth: '100%',
              display: 'block',
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  );
```

These solutions have not worked and the list still re-renders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

First of all a big thank you to everyones comments with potential solutions.

The issue was the loading of images was done by a useEffect function that would update every time a new image was added. Within this useEffect every image that the user had selected would have its signedURL generated. This isn't optimal as let's say the user added image1 - the useEffect would fire off and get the urls and display it. Now gif the user added image 2 so it went image 1 then image 2 the useEffect would fire off and get the urls for both - it should only get it for image 2 since we have image 1 already and this would cause a whole load of performance and re-rendering issues.